# Probabilistic Fuzzy System coding using Type 2 Fuzzy Systems

Tags: matlab, probability, fuzzy-logic, type-2-dimension

I've been trying to implement a Probabilistic Fuzzy System and I've came across the Type-2 Fuzzy System. From what I can understand is that since Type-2 Fuzzy has two membership functions for each antecedent element, as long as I can switch one of them to the probability density function of my dataset, the outcomes should be the same or similar. I wish someone could point it out in a Type-2 code where I could start working on the switch to include the PDF.

The two Type-2 codes I'm working on:

1. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29006-functions-for-interval-type-2-fuzzy-logic-systems
2. http://sipi.usc.edu/~mendel/software/